# DATETIME gives date without time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, insert

I have a SQL query which should convert a `datetime`. I have tried it in different ways but in every way something goes wrong.

```
INSERT INTO SETTLEMENT_WIN (COUNTRY,
                            COMMODITY,
                            MARKET_PLACE,
                            START_TIME,
                            END_TIME)
VALUES ('BE', 'EL', NULL, CONVERT(datetime, '2015-12-14 15:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), CONVERT(datetime, '2015-12-14 16:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
```

gives the error:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Argument data type varchar is
>   invalid for argument 3 of convert function.

```
INSERT INTO SETTLEMENT_WIN (COUNTRY,
                            COMMODITY,
                            MARKET_PLACE,
                            START_TIME,
                            END_TIME)
VALUES ('BE', 'EL', NULL, CONVERT(datetime, '2008-12-14 15:45', 120), CONVERT(datetime, '2015-12-14 16:00', 120));
```

Inserts the row but in `START_TIME` and `END_TIME` there is only the date but not the time

[image]

Then I tried to only insert the time but even then only the date was inserted (I am not allowed to change the date format).

```
Declare @Date1 datetime ='2008-12-14 15:45';
Declare @Date2 datetime ='2015-12-14 16:00';

INSERT INTO SETTLEMENT_WIN (COUNTRY,
                            COMMODITY,
                            MARKET_PLACE,
                            START_TIME,
                            END_TIME)
VALUES ('BE', 'EL', NULL, CONVERT(datetime, @Date1, 108), CONVERT(datetime, @Date2, 108));
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.

The `CREATE` statement for my table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [SETTLEMENT_WIN] ([SW_ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                               [COUNTRY] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
                               [COMMODITY] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
                               [MARKET_PLACE] [varchar](32),
                               [START_TIME] [date] NOT NULL,
                               [END_TIME] [date] NOT NULL,
                               CONSTRAINT [SW_PK]
                                   PRIMARY KEY ([SW_ID]));
```

Comment: Looks like your column is the datatype `date`. If you insert a `datetime` into a `date` column, it won't "automagically" become a `datetime` column. Just like if you insert a `decimal` into an `int` column.

Comment: By the way Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17 (SSMS 2017) isn't an RDBMS, it's an application used to interact with SQL Server (2008 - 2017). You can find out what version of SQL Server you are using by running `PRINT @@VERSION;`. It's important to know what version of SQL Server you are using (not SSMS), as the functions they have do differ. If you are stating what version you are using, always state the RDBMS version, not the application. Stating you are using SSMS 2017 is like stating "I am using Office 2016" when asked what version of Windows you have installed.

Comment: Could you post the DDL for your table (the `CREATE` statement) please?

Comment: @Larnu I have added the version and create statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly as I suspected:

```
[START_TIME] [date] NOT NULL,
[END_TIME] [date] NOT NULL,
```

If you provide a `datetime` value to a `date` datatype the time part of the value will be lost. Try:

```
DECLARE @d date;
SET @d = '2018-08-02T11:15:59.462'
SELECT @d;
```

Note it returns `2018-08-02`. A `date` is just that, a **date**. A `datetime`, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset` needs to be used to store a date **and** time. You'll need to fix your table to resolve this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SETTLEMENT_WIN ALTER COLUMN [START_TIME] datetime2(0) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.SETTLEMENT_WIN ALTER COLUMN [END_TIME] datetime2(0) NOT NULL;
```

Then you can insert a date and time value in your table.

Answer (score 1):

@SilverFullbuster, you will need the datatype column in START_TIME and END_TIME changed from date to [datetime].

from:

```
CREATE TABLE [SETTLEMENT_WIN] ([SW_ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                               [COUNTRY] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
                               [COMMODITY] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
                               [MARKET_PLACE] [varchar](32),
                               [START_TIME] [date] NOT NULL,
                               [END_TIME] [date] NOT NULL,
                               CONSTRAINT [SW_PK]
                                   PRIMARY KEY ([SW_ID]));
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE [SETTLEMENT_WIN] ([SW_ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
                               [COUNTRY] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
                               [COMMODITY] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
                               [MARKET_PLACE] [varchar](32),
                               [START_TIME] [datetime] NOT NULL,
                               [END_TIME] [datetime] NOT NULL,
                               CONSTRAINT [SW_PK]
                                   PRIMARY KEY ([SW_ID]));
```

and you can pull the starttime/endtime by extracting from the datetime column like this:

```
SELECT 
    SW_ID,  
    COUNTRY,    
    COMMODITY,  
    MARKET_PLACE,
    START_TIME=convert(varchar(8), START_TIME, 108),
    END_TIME=convert(varchar(8), END_TIME, 108)
FROM
    SETTLEMENT_WIN
```

and results will be like this:

[image]

Comment: This involves the OP recreating their table. If they already have data in it, would be lost (also, idealy provide the OP with a `DROP` statement). Personally, I would also recommend `datetime2`. Quoting from [datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): *"**Note**: Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable. time, datetime2 and datetimeoffset provide more seconds precision."*